# any pdf417 libraries for android SDK?

Tags: android, barcode

I have got something in my application for pdf417, So I need to know the SDK or jar or any library which i can use in my android application, does anyone know about this it will be really helpful, And I have already tired **Zxing** library for that but it lacks accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for free/open source PDF417 reader your options are probably limited. Realize that barcode scanning is a image processing problem (fuzziness, skew, tilt, reflection, etc.) that a number of companies have tackled and have built businesses around. And if they were around back when PDF417 started, they probably have various bits of IP (patents) protecting their investment. If the open source versions aren't responsive enough for you, you will have to look into purchasing some commercial code which will meet the requirements that you have. Good luck.

Comment: http://pdf417.mobi is not open source, but is free for non-commercial purposes